# How do you append to a list thats a value within a dictionary?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to append an instance to a `list` that's within a `dict`.

**I can't seem to figure out how to append to the list within the class without calling the list variable explicitly.**

My current code is almost 200 lines long but this example code is the gist of my problem.

For example, the user enters the name of the product `category(key)` they wish to **add** the item(instance) to. A `for` loop finds the `key` and verifies that the `key` exists.

The value of this `key` is a list.

**How do I append the instance to the list if it's inside of a dict as a value?**

Example output:

Please enter the category of the item you wish to add: 'Fruit'

Product categories:

Fruit | Canned goods

Please enter product name: 'Apples'

Please enter product price: 0.60

```
class Product():
    def __init__(self, name, price, category):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.category = category



category_choice = input('Please enter the category of the item you wish to add: ')

name = input('Please enter product name: ')

price = input('Please enter product price: ')



newProduct=Product(name='Apples', price=0.60, category=category_choice)

fruit = []
canned_goods = []
categories = {'Fruit': fruit, 'Canned Goods': canned_goods}
```

Comment: Append to WHAT instance?  You can certainly do `categories[category_choice].append(newProduct)`.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: And just to avoid confusion, `fruit` and `categories['Fruit']` are both bound to the SAME list.  Modifications to one will be seen with both names.

Comment: hmm, this throws a key error

Comment: The sample doesn't create a `Product` instance.

Comment: Note that your app requires that you type the category exactly as you have it listed: "Fruit" and "Canned Goods".  The capitalization must match.

Comment: @outis makes a good point;  `newProduct=(name...` should be `newProduct=Product(name...`.

Comment: You can try like [this](https://ideone.com/NMrtRw)

Comment: @TimRoberts Ya I just made a little typo there with the instance. I figured it out with the help of your top comment, I'll post it as an answer. Thank you